# Passing HTML in WordPress Shortcode arguments

Tags: functions, shortcode

I've searched a lot but didn't find a solid answer for my question. So I'm posting a new one here. If someone know how to do it, please answer it with an explanation.

Lets say I have a shortcode function

```
    function some_random_function($atts, $content = null) {
       extract(shortcode_atts(array(
          'text' => null
       ), $atts));

       $return_string = '<div class="some-class">'. $text . $content .'</div>';
       return $return_string;
    }
add_shortcode( 'example', 'some_random_function' );
```

I know that this function does not make any sense that why I'm using `$text` there where I can simply use `$content`. But this is just a simple function do dont judge it.

**Now the issue**
Now if I pass `[example text="lorem ipsum"]Lets roll[/example]` the shortcode will work fine as all are normal string. But if I pass `[example text="<a href="http://example.com">lorem</a> ipsum"]Lets roll[/example]` it will not work.

So can anyone tell me how can I pass html in the shortcode arguments so that they work properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have used the same quotation characters in 2 different contexts. You should write the shortcode in the following way:

`[example text='<a href="http://example.com">lorem</a> ipsum']Lets roll[/example]`

Then, "unescape" HTML entities on the shortcode output:

```
$return_string = '<div class="some-class">'. html_entity_decode($text) . $content .'</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks man for pointing out the issue and giving an helpful answer :) Thanks a lot man :)